# Rendering applies weird squares over my model

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

When I do the final render its all good until 99% and when it reaches 100% then it shows out of nowhere this random square.

How can i fix this? this square doen't exist in my collection. also i have tried CPU and GPU and same problem with booth of them.
UPDATE; i moved my camera away and this happened[![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAqrC.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAqrC.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Check for; - Render layers - Hidden objects (that still have the render flag turned on - Animation key frames (in case it's only there on one frame of a series)

Comment: nothing wrong with these

Comment: Can you post your file?

Comment: it says too large more tahn 2Mb

Comment: Google drive, or similar?

Comment: give me your email ill share with google drive

Comment: You should be able to post the link here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sd-EmmRmA1HseeKzuaB-vbJH0-Gel47n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your compositor;

[image]

It's showing up at the end because it's the last thing to be rendered and composited in.

Comment: soo what do i need to do ?

Comment: i removed it and it went all black after the final render

Comment: can ufix it and send me the drive link so i can see what you changed soo i know what i did wrong?

Comment: oh man thanks. i had the FAC full at the alfa over and i changed it to 0 and now it all good. i realy than kyou for your time mate. have a good one

Comment: @Phill Hello :). If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted **✓** :). Thanks.